# Why does an AVL tree with N nodes maintain $C \leq N/2$?

Tags: computer-science, trees

If $C$ denotes the number of "only child" nodes (a node is called an only child when its parent is not null and it doesn't have a sibling), why do we have that for every AVL tree with $N$ nodes, $C \leq N/2$?

Comment: I guess you mean that an "only-child" node has a parent, but no sibling.

Comment: yes, I'll change that , thank you .

Comment: OK.  Here's a hint: Every only child has a parent.  Can that parent be an only child?

Comment: If all of them have parents, then no.I just don't understand why the number of an "only-child" cannot be more than half of the nodes

Comment: If the parent of an only child is not an only child, and there is one parent for each only child, the number of only children cannot exceed the number of nodes that are not only children.  Note that the reason why the parent of an only child cannot be an only child has to do (in a very simple way) with the balancing property of AVL trees.

Comment: Ok, I understood what you mean, thank you